# Why are all the possible permutationss in the perturbative $S$-matrix calculations added together?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, s-matrix-theory, wick-theorem

I have a question regarding the calculation of the $S$-matrix. During the calculation of second order term of the $S$-matrix for e.g. the  Møller scattering $(e^
− + e^
− → e^
− + e^
−)$ $|i\rangle=|e^{-},\vec{p}_{1};e^{-},\vec{p}_{2}\rangle\,,|f\rangle=|e^{-},\vec{p}_{1}^{\prime};e^{-},\vec{p}_{2}^{\prime}\rangle$, we would only be interested in the following term, where only the photon fields are being contracted: \begin{equation}S_{M}^{(2)}=\mathrm{}-\frac{e^{2}}{2!}\int d^{4}x_{1}d^{4}x_{2}:[(\bar{\psi}^{-}\gamma^{\alpha}\psi^{+})_{x_{1}}(\bar{\psi}^{-}\gamma^{\beta}\psi^{+})_{x_{2}}]:i D_{F\alpha\beta}(x_{1}-x_{2})\end{equation}
(all other possible terms vanish in Moller scattering case)
Now, normal ordering puts all fields with "-" superscript to the left, and all fields with superscript "+" to the right. In this case:$$:[(\bar{\psi}_{a}^{-}\gamma_{ab}^{\alpha}\psi_{b}^{+})_{x_{1}}(\bar{\psi}_{c}^{-}\gamma^{\beta}_{cd}\psi^{+}_{d})_{x_{2}}]\!:=-\bar{\psi}^{-}_{a}(x_1)\bar{\psi}^{-}_{c}(x_2){\psi}^{+}_{b}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{d}(x_2)\gamma^\alpha_{ab}\gamma^\alpha_{cd}=\bar{\psi}^{-}_{c}(x_2)\bar{\psi}^{-}_{a}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{b}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{d}(x_2)\gamma^\alpha_{ab}\gamma^\alpha_{cd}$$
(and two other permutations) The two terms above are equal, but by interchanging two fields, you get a negative sign. Now, here is the part which confuses me:
In every textbook they say that the integral above has **four terms that we have to add together** (the two permutations above are the two topologically different ones). So in total we have two different Feynman diagrams that we "add" together (and multiply the total by two due to topologically equivalent terms): \begin{equation}S_{M}^{(2)}=\mathrm{}-e^{2}\int d^{4}x_{1}d^{4}x_{2}\big(\bar{\psi}^{-}_{c}(x_2)\bar{\psi}^{-}_{a}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{b}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{d}(x_2)\gamma^\alpha_{ab}\gamma^\alpha_{cd}-\bar{\psi}^{-}_{a}(x_1)\bar{\psi}^{-}_{c}(x_2){\psi}^{+}_{b}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{d}(x_2)\gamma^\alpha_{ab}\gamma^\alpha_{cd}\big)i D_{F\alpha\beta}(x_{1}-x_{2})\end{equation}
But this would imply that the normal ordering is not just ordering of the operators, but also **summing over all possible permutations** where all creation operators are on the left:$$:[(\bar{\psi}_{a}^{-}\gamma_{ab}^{\alpha}\psi_{b}^{+})_{x_{1}}(\bar{\psi}_{c}^{-}\gamma^{\beta}_{cd}\psi^{+}_{d})_{x_{2}}]\!:=2*\big(-\bar{\psi}^{-}_{a}(x_1)\bar{\psi}^{-}_{c}(x_2){\psi}^{+}_{b}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{d}(x_2)\gamma^\alpha_{ab}\gamma^\alpha_{cd}=\bar{\psi}^{-}_{c}(x_2)\bar{\psi}^{-}_{a}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{b}(x_1){\psi}^{+}_{d}(x_2)\gamma^\alpha_{ab}\gamma^\alpha_{cd}\big)$$ which is not obviously wrong, and hence my confusion.
Which step during this calculation was wrong? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling upon the same question, I have found a source which describes the process in a [very detailed way](https://www-user.rhrk.uni-kl.de/%7Eapelster/Vorlesungen/WS2021/v11.pdf). Pages 234-235 are the relevant ones for this question. In summary, after 'sandwiching' the S-matrix between our initial and final states, we have to commute the **operators** until we get rid of the states (i.e. until only delta functions remain). Due to anticommutation relations, we get 4 terms in total :-)